# Is there a way to be credited for work performed where employment taxes were returned to the worker after their employment ended?

Tags: retirement, security

My wife worked for almost 4 years when we were first married.  After she quit her job to stay home, she was advised that she could request her employment expenses be 'refunded' to her, including her FICA taxes, if she chose.  Being young college students with a baby and always needing money, we elected to get this money refunded.

It is now 40 years later and she would like to restore these lost credits if is possible, by repayment of these taxes or other administrative means.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you give any details on how this 'refund' happened? I'm not aware of any provision to refund FICA tax except (some) foreign students. Although some other payroll deduction items like 401K/etc and 'extra' insurance might be returned if you are no longer able to get their (nominal) benefits.

Answer (score 1):

***You didn't put what country you're in***, so I'll work off the basis you're in the United States.

I think you're going to have a very hard time accomplishing what you're talking about after such an extraordinary amount of time.  One has to assume that there would still be records that could be retrieved in order for anyone to determine the amount you'd have to pay, and after 40 years, the paper records would be long gone.

It's possible there might be microfiche somewhere, but I wouldn't have a clue how easy or possible it would be for it to be retrieved.

I *assume* you're wanting to repay this as a way to boost Social Security or other government benefits in your retirement, but it's really hard to say whether repaying the rebated money would make much, if any, difference.

This is really something you'll have to contact the IRS about, but unless they are trying to collect funds from you that they say you owe then it's highly unlikely they have any record of what you're asking about, and they probably don't even have a mechanism for accepting and crediting such monies.  The real issue here is the amount of time that has passed, because there would be little compelling reason for the government to keep detailed records (they perhaps maintain summaries, but little else) for extended periods.  We all have the impression the government knows all and never forgets, but that simply isn't the case.

Comment: For US, Social Security is administered by the Social Security Administration (www.ssa.gov) not IRS. FICA also includes Medicare Part A, which is administered by Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services (www.cms.gov -- yes, ONE 'm', go figure).

Comment: They were asking about taxes withheld and then refunded, so my belief is the IRS would be the right place to start, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The normal (withholding also Schedule SE) payments go through the IRS very briefly on their way to the 'trust funds' held by SSA and CMS, but the records of what credits you have and what benefits you qualify for are entirely handled by the latter. (Scarequotes because the trust funds are held in aggregate, not for a specific beneficiary as is the usual meaning of that term in the private sector.)